# FindControl of web page having multiple imagebutton

Tags: asp.net

i am using asp.net to create the seat-map of cinema view. i have multiple imagebuttons on my page. When user made no selection, all the seats are appear grey but when user wants to select a seat and will click, it will become golden. After selection of seats when user finally booked seats, it will become red.
My issue is this that i cant find my specific control of web page and it will always returns me with exception.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqq9W.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! But it will be better if you provide more information in your question. Curretly you asked nothing, nobody knows what happened to you. Please provide, for example the error log or the popup hint, for a better question.

Comment: basically i cant find my control on page. you can view the image, i just posted.